# Is there a way to know the global data size after compilation?

Tags: gcc, compilation

I am using GCC compiler for ARM. I want to know the global data size consumed by my code.

Is there a way to know this after compilation?

Should I generate any intermediate file (with some compiler options) to get this info?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the `size` command work for you?  It probably gives text size (code), and then data and bss (add to get the global data size).  I'm not sure if it will count constant data as 'code' or 'data'; it may place that in the read-only 'code' so it cannot be modified by accident.

Answer (score 1):

<sup>*Transferring a comment into an answer.*</sup>

Does the `size` command work for you?

It probably gives text size (code), and then data and bss (add to get the global data size). I'm not sure if it will count constant data as 'code' or 'data'; the compiler may place that in the read-only 'code' segment so that it cannot be modified by accident, in which case it probably gets counted as 'code' rather than as 'data' by `size`.

But it is the simplest, quickest tool to do the job if its answer is satisfactory.